# Cytoscape graph automove (with animation) when dragging a node

Tags: animation, graph, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I was looking to [this example](https://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/examples/onlinebrowse.html) of cola.js in which, when dragging a specific node, the other nodes have the capability to automove according to the new position of the node I'm dragging, and the thing I'm interested in is that you can see the graph transition to the new position in a sort of animation. I noticed that cytoscape does this with cytoscape-automove extention, but in every example I found there's no animation and no delay performed when nodes automove. Could you suggest any way to do this with cytoscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [cytoscape.js-cola](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola) which does more or less what `cola` does. The option `infinite: true` animates the graph while moving nodes as seen in your example.

You simply would need to add the cola [layout](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) to the `cy` instance – after installing the `cytoscape.js-cola`-module with `npm install cytoscape-cola` f.e.

```
let options = {
  name: 'cola',
  infinite: true

};
cy.layout( options );
cy.layout.run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :)